# unable to close output stream

Tags: ftp, aptana, aptana3, ftps

newbie here. I downloaded and installed Aptana Studio 3 yesterday and I keep getting the following message on uplad to my remote server (win 2008 R3 server) from my MAC (Lion 10.7.4): **Unable to close output stream** I only found one reference and tried that remedy without any luck. FTPS works fine using other programs.